# Get all javascript functions of an object from the constructor, BUT not those assigned using "this"?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I need to get all function names inside the constructor, **excluding those functions assigned with `this`**:

```
var MyObject = function (arg1, arg2) {
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;

    // Get all functions, i.e. 'foo', excluding 'arg1' and 'arg2'
};

MyObject.prototype.foo = function() {}
```

I have used Underscore.js, without luck. Assuming that the **actual parameters** are both functions:

```
var MyObject = function (arg1, arg2) {
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;

    // Array of object function names, that is 'foo', 'arg1' and 'arg2'
    var functions = _.functions(this);

     // Loop over function names
    _.each(functions, function (name) {}, this) {
        // Function arguments contain this.name? Strict check ===
        if(_.contains(arguments, this.name) {
            functions = _.without(functions, name); // Remove this function
        }
    }
};

MyObject.prototype.foo = function() {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for all of the functions defined by the prototype:

```
_.functions(MyObject.prototype);
```

Comment: Of course, thanks!!! Mind if I ask you to help me with [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946201/why-the-execution-context-this-of-prototypical-function-is-wrong-in-this-exa)?

Comment: Note that this will only return enumerable functions and will also get those on the prototype's `[[Prototype]]` as there is no `ownProperty` test. And since underscore uses `typeof` to test for functions, it will likely fail for host objects in some browsers (i.e. not return callable enumerable properties).

Answer (score 1):

The functions on `this` are those you have assigned inside the constructor plus those inherited from the prototype. So what you need to do is query the prototype for its functions:

```
var funcs = _functions(Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
```

The above works in all reasonably modern browsers. For early IE you could fall back to the non-standard

```
var funcs = _functions(this.__proto__);
```