# Why the execution context ("this") of prototypical function is wrong in this example?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, anonymous-function

Prototypical function `bar` is executed elsewhere, in a Node.js environment (where [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) should be available). I want **`this` inside `bar()` function to be the instance of my object**:

```
var Foo = function (arg) {
    this.arg = arg;

    Foo.prototype.bar.bind(this);
};

Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log(this); // Not my object!
    console.log(this.arg); // ... thus this is undefined
}

var foo = new Foo();
module.execute('action', foo.bar); // foo.bar is the callback
```

... why `bar()` logs `undefined` and `this` is not my instance? Why the execution context was not changed by the `bind` call?

Comment: In addition to what Matt said, every time you call `Foo` you are going to bind a different `this`. If you are calling the function as `foo.bar`, why use `bind` at all? Also, `this` is not "context", it's a special value of functions that is one parameter of their [execution context](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10), along with all the other variables and scope chain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a value - the newly bound function - but you just discard that value. `Function.bind` does not alter `this` (that is, its invocation context), nor does it alter its arguments (`this`).

> Is there another way to get the same result?

Doing it inside of the constructor function is actually wrong, because `bar` lives on `Foo.prototype`, so binding it to any one instance of `Foo` would break `this` for all other `Foo.bar` calls! Bind it where you *mean* it:

```
module.execute('action', foo.bar.bind(foo));
```

Or – maybe even simpler – don't define `bar` on the prototype at all:

```
var Foo = function (arg) {
    this.arg = arg;

    function bar () {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.arg);
    }

    this.bar = bar.bind(this);
};

var foo = new Foo();
module.execute('action', foo.bar);
```

Comment: That is, I need to assign the return value? Is there another way to get the same result? I don't like the idea of re-assign the function...

Comment: I'll take some time to fully understand your answer, in the meanwhile... really thank you!